# Running a script on multiple checkboxes with loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a file, I want to use it on my mobile phone. I'm trying to send an email to contact every time I check one of the boxes. For now, I'm doing a function for every checkbox, 20 in total. Is there a way to do it in a loop? Thanks a lot for your help.

And here is my code:

```
function onEditTriggerCourse1(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Courses Attribuées");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "g2") {
    sheet.getRange('a2').setValue(new Date());
    sendValidation1()
    
    range.uncheck();
    
    } else  {
    range.uncheck()
  }
}
}

function onEditTriggerCourse2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Nouveau Client");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "g3") {
    sheet.getRange('a3').setValue(new Date());
    sendValidation2()
    range.uncheck();
    
    } else  {
    range.uncheck()
  }
}
}


function sendValidation1() {
 var recipient1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("email1").getValue();
 var subject1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("subject2").getValue();
 var body1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("body1").getValue();
 var nameOfSender1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("sender1").getValue();;
   var message = {
    to: recipient1,
    subject: subject1,
    body: body1,
    name: nameOfSender1,
  }

   MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

function sendValidation2() {
 var recipient2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("email1").getValue();
 var subject2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("subject2").getValue();
 var body2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("body2").getValue();
 var nameOfSender2=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("sender2").getValue();;
   var message = {
    to: recipient2,
    subject: subject2,
    body: body2,
    name: nameOfSender2,
  }

   MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: Your examples are not consistent with your sample sheet.  I think If your checkbox is on G2 then your date should be placed on a2.  Yes / No ?

Comment: Personally I would put the names of the functions you wish to call into the spreadsheet. Perhaps with validation  and exceute them by name.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Thanks all. Cooper I edited the script, you are right. I’m a bit tired today so I did this kind of mistake. 
Thanks the Master. I didn’t know about the address. I removed the file and will do a table tomorrow. Here is night time. 
Best to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [checkboxButtons_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119054769?msgid=120084104) script with these parameters:

```
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        description: 'Send email',
        rangeToWatch: e.source.getRange('Courses Attribuées!G2:G'),
        triggerValue: true,
        resetValue: false,
        action: {
          run: (parameters, event) => {
            e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue(new Date());
            MailApp.sendEmail(parameters.message);
          },
          parameters: {
            message: {
              to: e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue(),
              subject: e.range.offset(0, -3).getValue(),
              body: e.range.offset(0, -2).getValue(),
              name: 'Julien',
            },
          },
        },
        messagePost: `Sent email to ${e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue()}`,
        event: e,
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]
```

Then rename the `onEdit(e)` function to `onEditCheckbox(e)` and set it to run on an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Delete any other triggers you may have set up.

You can delete the `modifyCounter_()` and `resetAllCounters_()` functions in the `checkboxButtons_` script as they are not needed here.

Comment: Thank you doubleunary, this looks very interesting as well ! the answer I receive earlier works well for me though!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating function per checkbox, create an **onEdit Installable Trigger** function and utilize its **event object** to get the row and column of the edited cell, then use those attributes to get the necessary details such as receipient, sender, email and body. You can also use those attributes to determine which row to set the date.

Here I refactor your code:

```
function myOnEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if(col == 7 && row > 1 && sheet.getName() == 'Courses Attribuées' && e.value == 'TRUE'){ //function will only works if the edited cell is the checkbox
      sheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date())
      var recipient = sheet.getRange(row, 8).getValue(); //get the column H of the edited cell row
      var subject = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); //get the column B of the edited cell row
      var body = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue(); //get the column I of the edited cell row
      var sender = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue(); //get the column C of the edited cell row
      sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, sender)
      range.uncheck()
  }
}


function sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, sender){
  var message = {
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    name: sender
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message)
}
```

### Demo:

**Before:**

[image]

After:

[image]

Email:

[image]

*Note: You can edit the **recipient, subject, body and sender** by changing the 2nd parameter of `getRange()` in the **sendEmail** function. In my code, I only pick what I think will fit and just to test the **sendEmail** Function. Also, let me know if the code I provided works and if you have any questions.*

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Thank you so much, Nikko !!! This is absolutely perfect and I feel very grateful for your work!!!